# Align text under background

Tags: html, css

I've got a problem with CSS. I need my text to align under the arrow (background image). **But the background image has to stay to the top left of the div.**

Here is what I mean:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/LYKTdih.png]

The text is right under the arrow now, but I want it to be aligned in the center under the arrow. How do I go about this?

**HTML**

```
<div class="defArrow" id="def_red_low">
    RED
</div>
<div class="defArrow" id="def_yellow">
    YELLOW
</div>
<div class="defArrow" id="def_green">
    GREEN
</div>
<div class="defArrow" id="def_blue">
    BLUE
</div>
<div class="defArrow" id="def_red_high">
    RED
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.defArrow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 107px;
    left: 42px;
    float: left;
    background: url('../images/up_arrow.png') no-repeat top center;
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 60px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well please provide css related to given code too as no css for defArrow class and others.

Comment: Sorry, it is fixed now, copied the css out of my old file.

Comment: means your issue got solved?? ok

Comment: No, I just copied the wrong code out of the wrong file. The problem still exists. What I ment by fixed was the OP is fixed.

Comment: sorry but i got this from your given code http://jsfiddle.net/nkeutmmg/ is this the issue you are talking about?

Comment: @Leothelion No, that is because it gives every arrow its own position in a javascript file. In your fiddle, you could use this arrow: http://i.imgur.com/M79h2Si.png and do `#def_yellow { left: 200px; }` so you can try it out with yellow. JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nkeutmmg/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can improve width of div and set text align as center. Your div allready is absolute. So you can use center of the div as relative zero. For my css, it is 51px

```
.defArrow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 107px;
    left: 42px;
    float: left;
    background: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/72/Dark_Green_Arrow_Up.png') no-repeat top center;
    display: block;
    background-size:20px 20px;
    background-position:center top;
    width: 101px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 60px;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align:center
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/00r2h8a4/)

Comment: I've had it this way aswell, but this also moves the arrow. The arrow needs to be in the same position, and the text under it. Because the location needs to be precise, and the left property is calculated in jQuery according to a database record. (JSFiddle of what it looks like on my screen:  jsfiddle.net/nkeutmmg/1/ )

Comment: @LJa yes so you keep your div width stabile and use a relative zero point. As you calculating your arrow position for your relative zero point. In your example your point is "0" already, in my codes it is "51". I.E. if your div's left value is 100px, arrow point outs 151px

Answer (score 2):

If you want to leave background positioned in `top left` of the div, then you need to wrap your content in another `absolute` div and align it with arrow picture.
 Here's some [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2u3o8jp0/).

**HTML**

```
<div class="defArrow" id="def_red_low">
    <div class="arrows-text">YELLOW</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.defArrow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 107px;
    left: 42px;
    float: left;
    background: url('../images/up_arrow.png') no-repeat top center;
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 60px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.arrows-text{
     position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-100px;
    width:200px;
    text-align:center;

}
```

Although, i think to change your background position to `top center` and `text-align:center;` your content is smarter way.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="colors"></div>

<div class="defArrow arrowRed" id="def_red_low">
    RED
</div>
<div class="defArrow arrowYellow" id="def_yellow">
    YELLOW
</div>
<div class="defArrow arrowGreen" id="def_green">
    GREEN
</div>
<div class="defArrow arrowBlue" id="def_blue">
    BLUE
</div>



.colors{
    border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
    height:20px;

}

.defArrow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;  
    float: left;
    background: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/72/Dark_Green_Arrow_Up.png') no-repeat top center;
    background-size:20px 20px;
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 60px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.arrowYellow{
    left: 100px; 
}

.arrowGreen{
    left: 200px;   
}

.arrowRed{
    left: 300px;   
}

.arrowBlue{
    left: 400px;   
}
```

You can try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/1xpqhe6m/1/)!

Thanks to Kamuran for the arrow link :).

Answer (score 1):

```
.defArrow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 107px;
    left: 42px;
    float: left;
    background: url('../images/up_arrow.png') no-repeat top center;
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 60px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

You need to remove width from your css code. Because according to your code your text should come in center but when your are using `width:20px` which is very less that's why its seems to be aligned left.

Try removing width from css it will work fine.